# Removing Documents from a Google Document AI Processor Dataset in Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am currently working on a project involving Google Document AI, and I need assistance with removing documents from a Processor dataset using Python. I have tried various approaches but haven't been able to find a solution.

Here's what I have done so far:

- I have set up a Processor in Google Document AI.
- I have successfully uploaded documents to the Processor dataset.
- Now, I need to remove specific documents from the dataset programmatically using Python.
- I have reviewed the Google Cloud Document AI documentation (in particular [this part](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/projects.locations.processors.dataset/batchDeleteDocuments)), but I couldn't find any clear guidance on how to achieve the deletion.

The code we used is the follwoing:

```py
import io

from google.cloud import documentai_v1beta3
from google.cloud.documentai_v1beta3 import DocumentId

PROCESSOR_LOCATION = "eu"
PROJECT_NUMBER = {
    "DEV": "123456789",
    "PROD": "123456789"
}
PROCESSOR_ID_CDE = {
    "DEV": "abcdefghijk",
    "PROD": "abcdefghijk"
}

# Create DocumentId objects and set the gcs_managed_doc_id attribute
doc_id1 = DocumentId(document_id="gs://test/raw_data/training/abc.pdf")
doc_id2 = DocumentId(document_id="gs://test/raw_data/training/xyz.pdf")

ENV_DEST = "DEV"


def sample_batch_delete_documents():
    # Create a client
    opts = {"api_endpoint": "eu-documentai.googleapis.com"}
    client = documentai_v1beta3.DocumentServiceClient(client_options=opts)

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    dataset_documents = documentai_v1beta3.BatchDatasetDocuments.IndividualDocumentIds(document_ids=[doc_id1, doc_id2])
    batch_dataset_documents = documentai_v1beta3.BatchDatasetDocuments()
    batch_dataset_documents.individual_document_ids = dataset_documents
    request = documentai_v1beta3.BatchDeleteDocumentsRequest(
        dataset=f"projects/{PROJECT_NUMBER[ENV_DEST]}/locations/{PROCESSOR_LOCATION}/processors/{PROCESSOR_ID_CDE[ENV_DEST]}/dataset",
        dataset_documents=batch_dataset_documents,
        timeout=300  # 300 seconds
    )
    print(request)

    # Make the request
    operation = client.batch_delete_documents(request=request)
    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
    response = operation.result()

    # Handle the response
    print(response)
```

The error message that I get is the following:

```
Error Message
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/tmp/ipykernel_13116/441287119.py in <module>
----> 1 sample_batch_delete_documents()
 
/var/tmp/ipykernel_13116/2850527411.py in sample_batch_delete_documents()
    39     print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
    40
---> 41     response =operation.result()
    42 
    43     # Handle the responseh
 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py in result(self, timeout, retry, polling)
   254         """
   255
--> 256         self._blocking_poll(timeout=timeout,retry=retry,polling=polling)
   257
   258         ifself._exception isnotNone:
 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py in _blocking_poll(self, timeout, retry, polling)
   135
   136         try:
--> 137             polling(self._done_or_raise)(retry=retry)
   138         exceptexceptions.RetryError:
   139             raise concurrent.futures.TimeoutError(
 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py in retry_wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
   352                 sleep_generator,
   353                 self._timeout,
--> 354                 on_error=on_error,
   355             )
   356
 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py in retry_target(target, predicate, sleep_generator, timeout, on_error, **kwargs)
   189     forsleep insleep_generator:
   190         try:
--> 191             return target()
   192
   193         # pylint: disable=broad-except
 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py in _done_or_raise(self, retry)
   117     def_done_or_raise(self,retry=None):
   118         """Check if the future is done and raise if it's not."""
--> 119         if notself.done(retry=retry):
   120             raise_OperationNotComplete()
   121
 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/operation.py in done(self, retry)
   172             bool:Trueifthe operation iscomplete,Falseotherwise.
   173         """
--> 174         self._refresh_and_update(retry)
   175         returnself._operation.done
   176
 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/operation.py in _refresh_and_update(self, retry)
   161         ifnotself._operation.done:
   162             self._operation =self._refresh(retry=retry)ifretry elseself._refresh()
--> 163             self._set_result_from_operation()
   164
   165     defdone(self,retry=None):
 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/operation.py in _set_result_from_operation(self)
   133             ifself._operation.HasField("response"):
   134                 response = protobuf_helpers.from_any_pb(
--> 135                     self._result_type,self._operation.response
   136                 )
   137                 self.set_result(response)
 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/protobuf_helpers.py in from_any_pb(pb_type, any_pb)
    65         raise TypeError(
    66             "Could not convert {} to {}".format(
---> 67                 any_pb.__class__.__name__,pb_type.__name__
    68             )
    69         )
 
TypeError: Could not convert Any to BatchDeleteDocumentsResponse
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide me with guidance on how to approach this. I am open to suggestions on what I already tried or also any other method.

Comment: Hi @Mikkel, have you checked this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/2.17.0/google.cloud.documentai_v1beta3.services.document_service.DocumentServiceClient#google_cloud_documentai_v1beta3_services_document_service_DocumentServiceClient_batch_delete_documents) of batch\_delete\_documents  and deleting the set of documents in the python language ? Please let me know if this helped you or not

Comment: Thx for the comment, this is what we used (the documentation is already linked on the question above).

Comment: Are you facing any error while using the code that you shared ? If yes, could you provide the error message ?

Comment: Yes, we are indeed receiving an error message when running the provided code. I have added the error message above. Maybe you could help figure out what the issue is. It seems like the response we get is of type Any so we are likely not getting a response?